# php function run based on category

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I am trying to get functions (a) and (b) to fire when the proper $description is run but so far I haven't been able to figure it out. Its probably something really simple.

Server is locked into php 5.2

```
    add_filter( 'category_description', 'so_31889614_category_description', 10, 2 );
    function so_31889614_category_description ( $description, $category ) 
    {
//testing with var_dump shows [int(7)] [int(2)] and [int(3)] in the proper places on the pages
            var_dump( $category );
            if ( $category->term_id == 2 || $category->term_id == 3 ) {
                $description = a();
            } elseif ( $category->term_id == 7 ) {
                $description = b();
            } else {
            $description;
        }
        return $description;
    }

function a($content) {
//stuff
return $content;
}
function b($content) {
//stuff
return $content;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a `if is_category` statement issue.

Was able to solve my own problem with the following

```
add_filter( 'category_description', 'so_31889614_category_description', 10, 2 );
function so_31889614_category_description ( $description, $category ) 
{
    if( is_category( array(2,3) ) )  {
        $description = a($content . $output);
    } elseif ( is_category( array(7) ) )  {
        $description = b($output2);
    } else {
        $description = a($content . $output);
    }
    return $description;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 2 functions that are returning data, but you are not putting in the description your telling the functions to expect.

```
$description = a('Put description a here');

$description = b('Put description b here');
```

Comment: right thats what im trying to figure out, how do i get function a($content) to be run and its output displayed when $description = a is run

Comment: 'Put description a here' needs to be the output of function a after its run //stuff

Comment: Thanks for your help and the up vote. Got me thinking along the right lines.